# Varnish-Cache Time based access

Tags: varnish

I have in Apache something like this

```
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11\.22\.33\.[12]\d\d$ #As example allows from 100 till 200
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
    RewriteCond %{TIME} <20140113090000
    RewriteRule ^/access-on-monday/ http://www.mysite.com/ [NC,L,R=302]
```

which works perfect.

I need same for Varnish.
Because server behind LoadBalancer it gets X-Forwarded-For header with real client IP. I still check %{REMOTE_HOST} in Apache because rpaf_module is installed.
I added next in Varnish with helping [ipcast](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/ipcast) vmod

```
    import ipcast;
    acl office {
        "localhost";
        "11.22.33.100"/24; //Let's think that it matches with 11.22.33.100 - 11.22.33.200
    }
    sub vcl_recv {
            if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For !~ ",") {
                set req.http.xff = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
            } else {
                set req.http.xff = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "^[^,]+.?.?(.*)$", "\1");
            }
            if (ipcast.clientip(req.http.xff) != 0) {
                error 400 "Bad request";
            }
            if (!client.ip ~ office) {
                set req.http.X-Redir-Url = "http://" + req.http.Host + "/";
                error 751 "Found";
            }
    }
```

Then in vcl_error I make redirect but it doesn't matter here.
My question is it possible to make timebased access like in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You are limited with simple VCL but Varnish allow to do much more than simple statements.
You can enhance and drive your workhorse with inline-C or VMODs, and do this job in C.

For example, if you want to do add timebased access from :

```
backend server_available_in_2014 {
  .host="127.0.0.1";
  .port="8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
   set req.backend = server_available_in_2014; # IT MUST BE AVAILABLE ONLY in 2014
}
```

You can convert your date `201401010000` into an UNIX timestamp `1389617122`, and write simple inline-C :

```
backend server_available_in_2014 {
    .host="127.0.0.1";
    .port="8080";
}

C{
double TIM_real(void);
}C

sub vcl_recv {
    C{
            if (TIM_real() > 1389617122.0) {
                    VRT_l_req_backend(sp, VGCDIR(_server_available_in_2014));
            }
    }C
}
```

`TIM_real()` is returning a current timestamp (look at **varnish/lib/libvarnish/time.c**) and `VRT_l_req_backend` statement is exactly the same as `set req.backend = server_available_in_2014;`, but written in C instead of VCL.

If you want more tweaks, you can compile your VCL into C by executing the following command:  `varnishd -f default.vcl -C`

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot. That makes good hint how to proceed. Actually I have this server online all the time, But the fact that inline-C can make much more than VCL is enough to think about right way.

Comment: Note that it will be easier to create a VMOD if your code is more complex that my example. It's worth it !